# MessageBoxEx sometimes shows as hollow window, border only, and only on Windows 11

Tags: winapi

At places in my app where I call `MessageBoxEx()` to display a question or information, only the dialog's border and its title are shown. No message and no buttons are visible. And the dialog is transparent, so it shows whatever is behind it.

I can hit that place in the app ten times and nine times it displays just fine, but once in a while the box is hollow, and if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then again invoke the command that shows a message box, it will display correctly.

My app is almost 20 years old (well, most of the code is, I make changes all the time), and I have never seen this before, just this one fresh Windows 11 install.

Is it me, or maybe I should ask my client to wait until the next update maybe?

```c
UINT  msgStyle = MB_TASKMODAL;

if (...) {
    msgStyle |= MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK;
    titleText = "Stop";
}
else {
    msgStyle |= MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_OKCANCEL;
    titleText = "Pitanje";
}

itemHit = MessageBoxEx (NULL, errMsg, titleText, msgStyle, MAKELANGID(LANG_CROATIAN, SUBLANG_DEFAULT));
```

(the word *Pitanje* means *Question* in Croatian)

Comment: Sounds like your app may have a GDI resource leak. You could check using Task Manager.

Comment: By enabling GDI column in Task manager? https://www.deleaker.com/blog/2021/12/16/gdi-leaks-how-to-identify-and-fix-them/ Well, I have 91 objects before MessageBoxEx(), then 92, then a new window appears (361 GDI objects) and as I close it I'm again at 91. Repeated many times, back to 91 - on my Win 10. I'll check on Win11 tomorrow

Comment: I've also seen Windows dialogs misbehave if you give it text that is **tooooo** long. Which can happen sometimes with error messages with huge stack traces. Might try trimming the text in the box to something like 1,000 characters. Also check for perhaps single lines of text that are *reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeealy* long, and cause it to try to create a dialog that is 32,000 pixels wide.

Comment: No, messages are rather short, maybe up to 50, 60 characters max.

Comment: Sounds like the dialog is simply not getting painted.  You'd only see the window frame but not its content.  Happens when the message loop is getting a flood of messages so it never gets around to delivering a WM_PAINT.  Spy++ can show what happens.

Comment: Regarding GDI objects, as I have a window showing something, 124 objects, call MessageBoxEx, 129 objects, dismiss it, 128 objects, show, 129, dismiss, 128, show, 129,... As if the first time I call MessageBoxEx it retains 4 objects forever. Observed on my Win10.

Comment: @Hans Passant - used Spy++ last time on XP but somehow I'll find the way - on my computer, but my client does not have the VS installed. And, the ghosted message boxes were seen after a restart, a cheap i3 laptop running Win11Pro. Maybe computer had too much to do at that point, tomorrow I'll wait till processor drops bellow 10% in Task Manager.

Comment: @IgorD I cannot reproduced it in win11. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AizIu.png  I use it in `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`. After multiple openings and closure, everything works fine. Can you show more details on that? Such as video, picture or a minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: Today I can't reproduce this problem. Seems like it was something related to the fresh install or maybe the computer did some updates in the meantime - today everything works as expected: MessageBoxEx() paints itself every single time. My app is the same as it was yesterday.